# Reaction of cyclopropane with hot potassium permanganate

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons, organic-oxidation

Hot potassium permanganate is usually used as an oxidising agent, and cyclopropane being an unstable three membered ring undergoes reaction with several reagents such as bromine, $\ce{HBr}$, metal adsorbed with hydrogen, etc.

However, I don't know for a fact if cyclopropane undergoes oxidation with hot permanganate – and I couldn't really find much data online.

[image]

If at all cyclopropane doesn't react, what happens with its methyl derivative? Does it get oxidised to the corresponding acid?